# How to tell a function to use the default argument values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `foo` that calls [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose):

```
import math
def foo(..., rtol=None, atol=None):
    ...
    if math.isclose(x, y, rel_tol=rtol, abs_tol=atol):
        ...
    ...
```

The above fails in [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) if I do not pass `rtol` and `atol` to `foo`:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

I do not want to put the system default argument values in my code (what
if they change down the road?)

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
import math
def foo(..., rtol=None, atol=None):
    ...
    tols = {}
    if rtol is not None:
        tols["rel_tol"] = rtol
    if atol is not None:
        tols["abs_tol"] = atol
    if math.isclose(x, y, **tols):
        ...
    ...
```

This looks long and silly and allocates a `dict` on each invocation of
`foo` (which calls itself recursively so this *is* a big deal).

So, what is the best way to tell [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) to use the default
tolerances?

PS. There are several related questions. Note that I do *not* want to know the actual default arguments of [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) - all I want it to tell it to use the defaults whatever they are.

Comment: you can grab the values of the default args: [Get a function argument's default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value) and come up with a way to define your function using those values. There's probably a way using `functools.partial`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670665/conditionally-passing-arbitrary-number-of-default-named-arguments-to-a-function but you will not find better answer in it.

Comment: @pault I tried `inspect.signature(math.isclose)` and it fails with `ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function isclose>`.

Comment: @Sanyash It works for me in python 3.7.2.

Comment: @Aran-Fey indeed, in 3.7.2 it works, but not in 3.6.6

Comment: Could you use an if else? For example: `if rtol and math.isclose(x, y, rel_tol=rtol, abs_tol=atol):` `elif math.isclose(x, y):`

Comment: Define a recursive helper function that `foo` calls so you only have to define the dict once.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: this is _precisely_ what I am trying to avoid, the a deleted answer.

Comment: @sds You just want a single if statement, not two of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using default arguments in a function with variable arguments. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967210/using-default-arguments-in-a-function-with-variable-arguments-is-this-possible)

Comment: If MartijnPieters' answer doesn't work for you, I would honestly just do what you already have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it would be with variadic argument unpacking:

```
def foo(..., **kwargs):
    ...
    if math.isclose(x, y, **kwargs):
        ...
```

This would allow you to specify `atol` and `rtol` as keyword arguments to the main function `foo`, which it would then pass on unchanged to `math.isclose`.

However, I would also say that it is idiomatic that arguments passed to `kwargs` modify the behaviour of a function in some way other than to be merely passed to sub-functions being called. Therefore, I would suggest that instead, a parameter is named such that it is clear that it will be unpacked and passed unchanged to a sub-function:

```
def foo(..., isclose_kwargs={}):
    ...
    if math.isclose(x, y, **isclose_kwargs):
        ...
```

You can see an equivalent pattern in `matplotlib` (example: [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) - `subplot_kw` and `gridspec_kw`, with all other keyword arguments being passed to the `Figure` constructor as `**fig_kw`) and `seaborn` (example: [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) - `subplot_kws`, `gridspec_kws`).

This is particularly apparent when there are *mutiple* sub-functions you might want to pass keyword arguments, but retain the default behaviour otherwise:

```
def foo(..., f1_kwargs={}, f2_kwargs={}, f3_kwargs={}):
    ...
    f1(**f1_kwargs)
    ...
    f2(**f2_kwargs)
    ...
    f3(**f3_kwargs)
    ...
```

**Caveat:**

Note that [default arguments are only instantiated once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887079/why-does-initializing-a-variable-via-a-python-default-variable-keep-state-across), so you should not modify the empty `dicts` in your function. If there is a need to, you should instead use `None` as the default argument and instantiate a new empty `dict` each time the function is run:

```
def foo(..., isclose_kwargs=None):
    if isclose_kwargs is None:
        isclose_kwargs = {}
    ...
    if math.isclose(x, y, **isclose_kwargs):
        ...
```

My preference is to avoid this where you know what you're doing since it is more brief, and in general I don't like rebinding variables. However, it is definitely a valid idiom, and it can be safer.

Comment: Further, *document* that any additional keyword arguments to `foo` are passed directly to `math.isclose`.

Comment: @chepner Yup, that's how the `FacetGrid` example does it. In addition, I think that in a case where keyword arguments are being passed on, an explicit `isclose_kwargs` or similar argument would be preferred to naked `**kwargs`.

Comment: Don't use mutable default arguments, however. `f1_kwargs=None` is better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you don't mutate it in your function itself, it makes your code less verbose to use `{}` as a default argument.

Comment: @gmds: I can still use `foo.__defaults__[0]['bar'] = 42` to mess with the defaults. And future refactorings of the function could easily miss that you defined these as defaults. Don't make it that easy to introduce errors.

Comment: @gmds: and don't underestimate the number of people that'll copy and paste from Stack Overflow and then do modify the dictionaries. Better to use best-practices *in your answers*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Anyone with the knowledge to modify default arguments in that way is good enough with Python to know that default arguments are instantiated only once. As for the rest, again, a sufficiently skilled programmer will know when to break the rules for a good reason - in this case, brevity. I have edited my answer to note the default argument pitfall, but I think that is sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

The correct solution would be to use the same defaults as `math.isclose()`. There is no need to hard-code them, as you can get the *current* defaults with the [`inspect.signature()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):

```
import inspect
import math

_isclose_params = inspect.signature(math.isclose).parameters

def foo(..., rtol=_isclose_params['rel_tol'].default, atol=_isclose_params['abs_tol'].default):
    # ...
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import math
>>> params = inspect.signature(math.isclose).parameters
>>> params['rel_tol'].default
1e-09
>>> params['abs_tol'].default
0.0
```

This works because `math.isclose()` defines its arguments using the [Argument Clinic tool](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html):

> [T]he original motivation for Argument Clinic was to provide introspection “signatures” for CPython builtins. It used to be, the introspection query functions would throw an exception if you passed in a builtin. With Argument Clinic, that’s a thing of the past!

Under the hood, the `math.isclose()` signature is actually stored as a string:

```
>>> math.isclose.__text_signature__
'($module, /, a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)'
```

This is parsed out by the `inspect` signature support to give you the actual values.

Not all C-defined functions use Argument Clinic *yet*, the codebase is being converted on a case-by-case basis. `math.isclose()` was [converted for Python 3.7.0](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c9ea933586ec0ac686c83d514c56876ac0e259e3).

You could use the `__doc__` string as a fallback, as in earlier versions this too contains the signature:

```
>>> import math
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> math.isclose.__doc__.splitlines()[0]
'isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0) -> bool'
```

so a slightly more generic fallback could be:

```
import inspect

def func_defaults(f):
    try:
        params = inspect.signature(f).parameters
    except ValueError:
        # parse out the signature from the docstring
        doc = f.__doc__
        first = doc and doc.splitlines()[0]
        if first is None or f.__name__ not in first or '(' not in first:
            return {}
        sig = inspect._signature_fromstr(inspect.Signature, math.isclose, first)
        params = sig.parameters
    return {
        name: p.default for name, p in params.items()
        if p.default is not inspect.Parameter.empty
    }
```

I'd see this as a stop-gap measure only needed to support older Python 3.x releases. The function produces a dictionary keyed on parameter name:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import math
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> func_defaults(math.isclose)
{'rel_tol': 1e-09, 'abs_tol': 0.0}
```

Note that copying the Python defaults is *very low risk*; unless there is a bug, the values are not prone to change. So another option could be to hardcode the 3.5 / 3.6 known defaults as a fallback, and use the signature provided in 3.7 and newer:

```
try:
    # Get defaults through introspection in newer releases
    _isclose_params = inspect.signature(math.isclose).parameters
    _isclose_rel_tol = _isclose_params['rel_tol'].default
    _isclose_abs_tol = _isclose_params['abs_tol'].default
except ValueError:
    # Python 3.5 / 3.6 known defaults
    _isclose_rel_tol = 1e-09
    _isclose_abs_tol = 0.0
```

Note however that you are at *greater* risk of not supporting *future, additional* parameters and defaults. At least the `inspect.signature()` approach would let you add an assertion about the number of parameters that your code expects there to be.

Comment: `inspect.signature(math.isclose)` does not work in Python 3.6

Comment: @sds: right, the Argument Clinic conversion was done for 3.7. Tough luck for you!

Comment: Also `math.isclose.__text_signature__` contains `None` for me on Python3.6.6.

Comment: @Sanyash: yes, that's what my answer is saying. That it requires 3.7 or newer for this to work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it would be useful if you added your generic fallback on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value).

Answer (score 7):

There really aren't many ways to make a function use its default arguments... You only have two options:

1. Pass the real default values
2. Don't pass the arguments at all

Since none of the options are great, I'm going to make an exhaustive list so you can compare them all.

- #### Use `**kwargs` to pass through arguments

  Define your method using `**kwargs` and pass those to `math.isclose`:

  ```
  def foo(..., **kwargs):
      ...
      if math.isclose(x, y, **kwargs):
  ```

  Cons:

  - the parameter names of both functions have to match (e.g. `foo(1, 2, rtol=3)` won't work)
- #### Manually construct a `**kwargs` dict

  ```
  def foo(..., rtol=None, atol=None):
      ...
      kwargs = {}
      if rtol is not None:
          kwargs["rel_tol"] = rtol
      if atol is not None:
          kwargs["abs_tol"] = atol
      if math.isclose(x, y, **kwargs):
  ```

  Cons:

  - ugly, a pain to code, and not fast
- #### Hard-code the default values

  ```
  def foo(..., rtol=1e-09, atol=0.0):
      ...
      if math.isclose(x, y, rel_tol=rtol, abs_tol=atol):
  ```

  Cons:

  - hard-coded values
- #### Use introspection to find the default values

  You can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to determine the default values at run time:

  ```
  import inspect, math

  signature = inspect.signature(math.isclose)
  DEFAULT_RTOL = signature.parameters['rel_tol'].default
  DEFAULT_ATOL = signature.parameters['abs_tol'].default

  def foo(..., rtol=DEFAULT_RTOL, atol=DEFAULT_ATOL):
      ...
      if math.isclose(x, y, rel_tol=rtol, abs_tol=atol):
  ```

  Cons:

  - [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) may fail on builtin functions or other functions defined in C

Comment: `inspect.signature(math.isclose)` does not work in Python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

Delegate the recursion to a helper function so that you only need to build the `dict` once.

```
import math
def foo_helper(..., **kwargs):
    ...
    if math.isclose(x, y, **kwargs):
        ...
    ...


def foo(..., rtol=None, atol=None):
    tols = {}
    if rtol is not None:
        tols["rel_tol"] = rtol
    if atol is not None:
        tols["abs_tol"] = atol

    return foo_helper(x, y, **tols)
```

Or, instead of passing tolerances to `foo`, pass a function which already incorporates the desired tolerances.

```
from functools import partial

# f can take a default value if there is a common set of tolerances
# to use.
def foo(x, y, f):
    ...
    if f(x,y):
        ...
    ...

# Use the defaults
foo(x, y, f=math.isclose)
# Use some other tolerances
foo(x, y, f=partial(math.isclose, rtol=my_rtel))
foo(x, y, f=partial(math.isclose, atol=my_atol))
foo(x, y, f=partial(math.isclose, rtol=my_rtel, atol=my_atol))
```